# Teradata String Manipulation

Tags: string, teradata

I have taken a good look at the Teradata Syntax reference to no avail

I have some rows with numbers:

```
ID
Mickey
Laura9
Larry59N
```

**How do I take away the integers from my rows?**

I understand that SUBSTR(id, 0, index(id, '%FORMAT%')) would work, but I don't know what could I enter in the %FORMAT% area to just find integers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use oTranslate to remove numbers:

```
 BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:

Select the_name, oTranslate( the_name, 'a0123456789','a')
from
( SELECT 'Larry59N' the_name FROM ( SELECT 'X' DUMMY ) a
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Laura9' FROM ( SELECT 'X' DUMMY ) b
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Mickey' the_name FROM ( SELECT 'X' DUMMY ) c
       ) d
;


 *** Query completed. 3 rows found. 2 columns returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

the_name oTranslate(the_name,'a0123456789','a')
-------- -----------------------------------------------------
Larry59N LarryN
Laura9   Laura
Mickey   Mickey
```

HTH.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a function native to Teradata that will accomplish this. I would suggest looking at the UDF's posted on the Teradata Developer Exchange ([link](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/madmac/2010/03/a-few-basic-scalar-string-udfs)). The function `eReplaceChar` in particular looks like it may help you accomplish what you are looking to do with this data. The UDF's found at the link above were published under the Apache 2.0 license so you should not have any problems using them.